# How does flink-sql deal with scenario like 'count(distinct )'

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

I need to calculate "Daily Active Users" in realtime using flink-sql and it is like a '`count(distinct )`' operation on daily data.

My question is, if `userA` logined this morning at 1am and flink add 1 to DAU as expected. Now, `userA` logined again at 10pm, how could flink-sql know the `userA` has been processed this morning? Does it need to repeatly do `count(distinct )` on the whole day's login log? If not, how does flink handle this senario?

Answer (score 3):

Distinct is a very expensive operation in streaming. If you don't use the time-based windows (`TUMBLE`,`SLIDE`, `SESSION`), the runtime must store all values in state forever because it needs to assume that another record could arrive at any point in the future.

However, you can set the option `table.exec.state.ttl` ([see here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/config.html#table-exec-state-ttl)) how long you want to keep those records in state. This might be one of the most important options when designing a SQL pipeline with long-running queries where the value space of an operator input is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

By real-time, I assume you mean in a Continuous Query?

See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tuning/streaming_aggregation_optimization.html

> By default, the unbounded aggregation operator processes input records
> one by one, i.e., (1) read accumulator from state, (2)
> accumulate/retract record to accumulator, (3) write accumulator back
> to state, (4) the next record will do the process again from (1).

The accumulator does not only keep the end result, but also enough data to produce the next result without reading all previous records again.

I guess in the case of count(distinct), it means keeping all unique users per day in the accumulator.